# How to add space *between* equations in Microsoft Word 2017 equation editor

Tags: microsoft-word

I cannot add extra space between two equations that are aligned on the = sign. This is in Microsoft Word 2017 equation editor on Windows 10.

For example, I want to add space between these two equations, but maintain the alignment on the = sign. It would be great to get 12 point space between them. Currently the two equations are squished up together (see screenshot below). If I add an extra carriage return to create a space between them, the alignment is lost.

[image: MS Word 2017 equation editor -- no space]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following to add space in between:

- Select both lines
- On the Home -> Paragraph -> Line and Spacing, select 1.5 or 2

On the image below, I selected 2 to show the spacing between the 2 equations.

Before                             After

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: That worked well. Thank you